# MySQL Python creating table with variable as name

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am working on a project with a friend and am new to sql databases. I want to have a database with tables named after the date they were created. I have tried multiple things but i thought .format() would be the best, but it didnt work. This is how it currently looks:

```
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
sql = "CREATE TABLE {table} (CEO VARCHAR(255), profits INTEGER(10))"
mycursor.execute(sql.format(table = d1))
```

i am also trying to insert into the database with .format:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO{table} (CEO, profits) values (%s, %s)"
mycursor.execute(sql.format(table = d1), (Company(c).get_CEO(), int(Company(c).get_profit())))
mydb.commit()
```

I get the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS. From your title and error, I have *assumed* you are using MySQL.

Comment: try to add space between `INTO` and `{table}` like `INSERT INTO {table} (CEO, profits) values (%s, %s)`

Answer (score 0):

You have no space between `INTO` and `{table}`